# Ruby on Rails / get count on self nested model (has_many / belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a self nested category model: which `has_many` and `belongs_to` it self

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :subcategories,   class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to  :parent_category, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

In the view I want to display not only the `@category.subcategories.count` but the count of all nested subcategories

how would I get that?

**~~~ UPDATE: ~~~**

In the categories controller I get the current category from the parameters like:

```
def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

now I want use in the view (but the following example doesn't give me all nested subcategories back)

```
<div>
    <%= @category.name %> has <%= @category.subcategories.count %> subcategories in total
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a recursive model method...

```
def deep_count
  count = subcategories.count
  subcategories.each { |subcategory| count += subcategory.deep_count }
  count
end
```

If in your design it's possible for a child to be the parent of an ancestor

(e.g. "4x4" -> "Jeep" - > "SUV" -> "4x4" -> ...)

Then you could end up with a stack overflow. To avoid that you can track categories to ensure you don't deep_count them twice...

```
def deep_count(seen_ids=[])
  seen_ids << id
  count = subcategories.count
  subcategories.where("id NOT IN (?)", seen_ids).each do |subcategory|
    count += subcategory.deep_count(seen_ids)
  end
  count
end
```

Comment: would that method sit in the model??

Comment: awesome works great!!!! So the line in the view is like that: `<%= @category.name %> has <%= @category.deep_count %> subcategories in total` Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Would this ever lead to infinite recursion?

Comment: @RichPeck only if a descendant is a parent of self or an ancestor, but good point.  I've edited to handle that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to `@SteveTurczyn`'s epic answer, you *may* wish to look at using one of the `hierarchy` gems (we use [`acts_as_tree`](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree)).

Not only will this extract your `has_many :subcategories` association, but provides a myriad of functionality to allow you to better handle nested objects.

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_tree order: "name"
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
@category = Category.find x

@category.children           #-> collection of subcategories
@category.parent             #-> Category record for "parent"

@category.children.create name: "Test" #-> creates new subcategory called "test"
```

Because `acts_as_tree` uses `parent_id`, you wouldn't have to change anything in your database.

--

You'd still be able to use the `deep_count` method:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree order: "name"

  def deep_count
     count = children.count
     children.each {|child| count += child.deep_count }
     count
  end
end
```

I'm sure there must be a way to count the "children" but I've not got any code at hand for it.

---

The main benefit of it is the recursion with displaying your categories. For example, if a `Post has_many :categories`:

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<%= render @post.categories %>

#app/views/categories/_category.html.erb
<%= category.name %>

Subcategories:
<%= render category.children if category.children.any? %>
```

--

Just seems a lot cleaner than two `ActiveRecord` associations.

Comment: thanks for the hint, will look into it in the future. well described, thanks!